# Different gauge wire for a 40 amp 240v

Tags: electrical, 240v

I am moving my range. I need an extra 4 feet. It is very difficult to run new wire. It is 8 gauge aluminum wire (says on sleeve 2-8). Can I connect 6 gauge aluminum to the 8 gauge aluminum  in a junction box for the extra 4 feet?

Comment: Will that junction box with the splice be accessible or buried in a wall cavity?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Please take our [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: The junction box will be accessible in the basement ceiling.

Comment: Then yes, you can. Make sure to use connectors approved for aluminum conductors, I would use what are called "Polaris" connectors. Polaris is a brand name, there are others. But before you do, make sure the terminals on the range will accept #6 conductors.

Comment: @JRaef You should type this up as an answer.

Comment: Was the original range run using a SEU cable (with the neutral wrapped around the hots) or a NM cable (with a separate bare wire that's being abused as a neutral)?

Comment: Can we have a photo of where the existing range wire ends, even? This matters quite a bit with regard to legally extending it...

Comment: To judge about the correct or incorrect wire cross section size if the size seems to be close to the 40A limit it would help to know all relevant factors like 

 1) mounting inside or close to insulation layers
 2) number and load of nearby wires 
 3) mounting inside tray or inside tubes, tube material
 4) ventilation of the area
 5) air temperature range
 6) allowed max. temperature of the cable
 7) wall material
 
All these conditions have a big impact on the max. load.
And some conditions could have been altered since the original installation was done.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, your plan to splice in a junction box in the basement is fine.  The junction box will need 32 cubic inches, so I'd consider a 4-11/16" square box as a minimum. JRaef's idea of a Polaris connector is the right concept, but you'll be better off with a "mini-Polaris" such as a [MAC Block](http://www.ilsco.com/latest-news/mac-block-splice-tap-connectors/).

Upsizing to #6 wire for the last 4 feet buys you nothing.  You can just stay with 8 AWG aluminum.

8-2 cable is also not legal for ranges (unless it is SEU cable with a ground in individual strands that spiral around the outside of the conductors.  There have been a fair number of incidents of installers using 8-2+ground cable illegally.  These cables have a single ground wire that is just a normal stranded wire like the conductors.

Comment: You can run 40A on 8AWG Al, but you need 75degC terminations to do so.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Oh, snap! I was sure it was one of those sizes that got a love letter from 240.4(D). But I guess not.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica -- 8AWG Al indeed is beyond the reach of 240.4(D)

Answer (score 0):

Too less power/AWG wiring for the kitchen range seems to be a standard problem.

Just to ignore the code could end in **serious problems** (insurance, law).

It could be solved by operating a low power range, running new wires/panels, using gas as proposed by Harper or by switching to 2 separate devices, i.e. a combination (hot air/ grill / microwave) oven and induction plates.
The last solution does have many advantages.

More details are here:
[need-a-new-range-but-only-have-30-amps](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/186939/need-a-new-range-but-only-have-30-amps/187094?noredirect=1#comment329734_187094)